# send one of multiple search result to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page `userLanding.jsp`
When a user performs a search the page will give multiple results.
I need to check selected dynamic result (succeeded so far),
Now the problem is I need to send/transfer/retrieve data of selected div to another page.

How can I do that?

Here is the code i am following to check which result is selected.

```
$('.demo-card-wide').click(function(){
    article = $(this).text(); 
});

$(document).on('click', '.demo-card-wide', function(){
    alert("clicked on result!!");
    var id = this.id;
    window.location = "http://localhost:8080/CarPool/test.jsp#"+id;  
});
```

Comment: What value are you trying to retrieve `id`?

Comment: What server language are you using? Sounds like you need to go read some tutorials.

Comment: id  is ID of selected div that i want to send/transfer to another page

Comment: i am using JSP,, but most of coding is in jquery,ajax

Comment: And you are wanting to get this value on the page that `window.location = "http://localhost:8080/CarPool/test.jsp#"+id;` sends you to?

Comment: exactly @DelightedD0D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are redirecting to a new page with the value you want set as the URL's hash, you can use `window.location.hash` to access that value on page load (though I wouldnt trust the data past that as it could be changed by the page after loading)

```
$(function(){
    var id = window.location.hash;
    // do something with id...
});
```

If you need to persist the data further than this, you might look into `localstorage` or a server side solution.

---

Just for grins, here is how I would do it (using `localstorage`):

Make this code available to both pages:

```
  /**
   * Feature detect + local reference for simple use of local storage
   * Use this like:
   * if (storage) {
   *    storage.setItem('key', 'value');
   *    storage.getItem('key');
   * }
   *
   */
  var storage;
  var fail;
  var uid;
  try {
    uid = new Date;
    (storage = window.localStorage).setItem(uid, uid);
    fail = storage.getItem(uid) != uid;
    storage.removeItem(uid);
    fail && (storage = false);
  } catch (exception) {}
  /* end  Feature detect + local reference */
```

On the first page have this:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.demo-card-wide', function() {
    if (storage) {
      alert("clicked on result!!");
      storage.setItem('article-id', this.id);
      window.location = "http://localhost:8080/CarPool/test.jsp";
    } else // some error message
  });
```

On the second page, do this:

```
  $(function() {
    if (storage) {
      var id = storage.getItem('article-id');
      // do something with id...
    }
  });
```

Comment: let me try this @DelightedD0D